# How do I traverse a remote (ftp) directory tree with Perl?

Tags: perl, ftp

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there any module like File::Find that works via ftp?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Net::FTP::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-FTP-Recursive).

Always search [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) to see if you find modules for what you want.

Comment: I'm confused about this module, the documentation is not very clear to me. I'm trying the `rdir()` method and it seems kind of pointless. Why does it need a filehandle to write to? `yoursub` gets passed a string containing the usual `ls -l` formatted output and it does **not** dive into subdirectories. What's the point? I was looking for something that scanned the tree and allowed the user's subroutine to do something with what's found, maybe passing it a hashref with infos about the file... or maybe I'm doing something wrong.