# Recursing remote directory tree via ftp in Perl (or other lang) to populate file hierarchy info only into MySQL - looking for existing libraries

Tags: mysql, perl, recursion, ftp, populate

I want to populate a MySQL database with the *information* (i.e. not the files/folders themselves but their names+ other info) from a remote directory via FTP, retaining the hierarchical positions of the files.

I'm looking for existing libraries that do some or all of this, particularly the parsing of the text/strings returned from ftp output.

I've done some research here already but not found anything quite close enough:

- [How can I read a file's contents
  directly with Perl's Net::FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824417/how-can-i-read-a-files-contents-directly-with-perls-netftp)
- [FTP Recursive…how to skip it if I
  already have the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503915/ftp-recursive-how-to-skip-it-if-i-already-have-the-file) (might be
  useful)
- [How do I traverse a remote (ftp)
  directory tree with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785774/how-do-i-traverse-a-remote-ftp-directory-tree-with-perl) (very
  close but there are bad reviews of
  this module, e.g. apparently, regex
  is broken and it doesn't recurse into
  directories, is this true? are there
  examples that work?
- [Download all images from a single
  directory of a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622006/download-all-images-from-a-single-directory-of-a-website) (this uses HTTP not FTP, but the concept is similar but not directly usable for my situation)

I would use the following approach to store the file hierachy in MySQL:

- [Storing folder hierarchy in
  relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719278/storing-folder-hierarchy-in-relational-database)

Just thought I would ask before I potentially re-invent the wheel. If I don't get answers I'll assume what I'm asking for doesn't exist in entirety yet so I would post what my approach would be (as I have done with other, different questions I have posted here). Thanks in advance if you can offer advice though.

Using Perl to do this is not mandatory, any other cross platform language would be OK, e.g. C, C++, Java, PHP, Python. It's just that I'm "in-the-zone" with Perl doing a lot of work using it at the moment but am open to other languages having programmed extensively with most of those listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [ncftpls](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpls.html) you can do a remote directory listing, and then you can parse it with Perl or any other language. You will need the `-R` option to recurse through subdirectories.

```shell
ncftpls -R ftp://ftp.example.com/
```

Comment: +1 looks good. Thank you very much. I'll read on up on it and feedback. I'll leave the question open for a little longer to give others the change to contribute. But, yes, this looks good. Thanks again.

Comment: Accepted answer. I think I have everything I need, including daxim's comment. Thankyou both.